# Why is my sql menu cycle returning one week behind?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using c# and sqlserver and have created a food menu that shows items in a cafe in a 3 week rotation. Here is my query:

```
Select [FoodItem] from FoodMenu WHERE [Week] = (DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) % 3) + 1  
AND [Station] = 'Entree' AND [Day] = CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 1 
THEN 7 ELSE DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) - 1 END
```

But starting this week it started showing one week behind, for instance, it would normally be showing the Entree menu items from the second week but it is showing the menu items from the first. Why is this?

Comment: Can you provide sample records for FoodMenu and the returned values from DATEPART for WEEK and DW?

Comment: Is the server's date/time zone set right?

Comment: Because last week was week 53 of 2015 and this week is week 2 of 2015. In both cases, wk %3 +1 returns the same - 3

Answer (score 1):

You're program isn't taking into account the New Year, it would be better to use a formula that takes the difference of some starting point and today :

```
/*Here start date would be some specified date where you want to start the rotation at 1 */
SELECT [FoodItem] 
FROM FoodMenu 
WHERE [Week] = (DATEDIFF(WEEK,@StartDate,GETDATE()) % 3) + 1
AND [Station] = 'Entree' AND 
  [Day] = CASE WHEN 
            DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 1 
                THEN 7 
            ELSE DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) - 1 
        END
```

This way you wont need to go in and manually adjust things when the year changes